# In Imagemagick what is the opposite of crop. Add padding to one side of an image

Tags: imagemagick

I know about extend and gravity.   I have an image and I want to increase its canvas size to 400x400 AND I want to take the existing image and place it at a specific X and Y in the canvas.  I have the Specific values, but I need the ability to move the image there.

Here is an Example.

```
 width = 52 
 page.x = 158
 400 - width - page.x = 190

 height = 107
 page.y = 146
 400 - height - page.y = 147
```

In this example the image needs to be resize from 52x107 to 400x400 and the image needs to start at 158x146 in this need 400x400 canvas.

Comment: It is always a good idea to attach an expected final image. 52x107 does not scale up to 400x400 so do you want the image cropped or distorted or is the 400x400 a different canvas not from the original image?

Answer (score 2):

If your not distorting the original 52x107 image, then it might be as simple as `-repage +{left}+{top}`.

```
# Given a 52x107 image.
convert -size 52x107 xc:orange 52x107.png
```

[image: 52x107.png]

```
# Create a blank canvas to act as the padding.
convert -size 400x400 xc:lime \( 52x107.png -repage +158+146 \) -flatten out.png
```

[image: out.png]

> In this example the image needs to be resize from 52x107 to 400x400 and the image needs to start at 158x146 in this need 400x400 canvas.

However it sounds like you *do* want to resize the small image to 400x400, and adjust offset w/ padding.

```
# Using rose: for example
convert -size 400x400! xc:lime \
        \( rose: -resize 400x400! -repage +158+146 \) \
        -flatten out2.png
```

[image: out2.png]

... *or* ... attempting something more dynamic

```
OFFSET=$(identify -format '+%[fx:(400-w)/2]+%[fx:(400-h)/2]' rose:)
convert rose: -repage $OFFEST \
        \( +clone -resize 400x400! -repage +0+0 \) \
        -swap 0,1 -flatten out3.png
```

[image: out3.png]

But, perhaps, I'm not understanding the OP question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I need to convert this into a slightly different style.  This is what I have convert ' . $img . '.png /gradient/gradient.png -clut  NOW I have that image and I want to apply what you have given to me to this image.  How would I do so?

Answer (score 2):

The "-extent" option, with a specified offset, does exactly what you want:

```
magick -size 52x107 xc:orange -background lime \
       -extent 400x400-158-146 52x107-400x400.png
```

The `-extent 400x400-158-146` option means "extend the image to 400x400, and place the upper left corner of the extended image at location (-158,-146) with respect to the original image."